# Compare String that Aren't Exact Match

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm doing a short answer quiz for a uni course. Basically students have to type in the answers/keywords. I use `preg_match_all()` to do the string comparison (user answer and answer in database). I was trying one word answer and it came out okay but there's a problem when it's a phrase being submitted.

```
    if(preg_match_all("/". $ans[$arr_ind]. "/i", " . $atext[$arr_ind] . ")){
            echo "<p align='justify'><img src='image/mark.png' border='0' width='20' height='20'></img><b> YOUR ANSWER: </b>". $ans[$arr_ind]. "</p>";
            $total = $total + 1;
            $correct = 1;
    }
    else
            echo "<p align='justify'><img src='image/cross.png' border='0' width='20' height='20'></img> <b>YOUR ANSWER: </b>". $ans[$arr_ind]. "</p>";
```

For example:

**Answer submitted:** hardware, software

**Answer in database:**

1. Hardware: processes data by executing instructions; provides input and output.
2. Software: instructions executed by the system.
3. Data: fundamental representation of facts and observation; raw facts.
4. Communications: to share data and processing among different systems; communication channel, interface hardware and software.

The function evaluated that as incorrect answer. I've looked up regular expression but don't think it's for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Atikah

Comment: Then you should tokenize the answer into individual words and match those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always split the answer into its individual parts and run the check:

```
$answers = explode(",", $ans[$arr_ind]);
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    $answer = trim($answer);
    if (stripos($atext[$arr_ind], $answer) !== false)
        // correct
    else
        // incorrect
}
```

I also answered your previous question, and I think the POSTed answers go into *$ans[]* correct? So that is what is referenced in the first line, but switch the arrays as necessary.

*stripos* will do the same thing as your *preg_match* with a little friendlier syntax and faster execution.

Comment: Also, since students may not use commas to separate data, you may want to explode by a space and then remove extraneous data like commas rather than the other way around as shown in my code.

Comment: Your solution did it for me :) Note taken for the explode. Thank you very much. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you suggest a way if I were to compare strings with more than one row of data?